# Jquery this element from inside if

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation

What I am trying to make is simple jquery wizard, I have 4 steps, ,button previous and next. Depending on what step u are on, when u click on next, line should fill in with gold color and circle should after that also fill in. So if you are on step2, clicking next, you would fill in line from circle 2 to circle 3. And so on...I managed to do it with 5 functions, one for each element, but I am sure it can be done with one simplier function. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.next').click(function () {
        if ($('.sirina').parent().prev('.krug').hasClass('stiglo')) {
            console.log(this);
            $('.sirina').animate({
                width: '150px'
            }, 1000, function () {
                $(this).parent().next('.krug').animate({
                    borderTopColor: '#E3B009',
                    borderBottomColor: '#E3B009',
                    borderLeftColor: '#E3B009',
                    borderRightColor: '#E3B009'
                }, 1000).addClass('stiglo');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Frenki/LbssU/3/

Now, problem is in line after console.log where I am animation all '.sirina' classes and not the one whos previous div has class 'stiglo' which is element that is inside function 'if'. But if I use 'this' then its refering to 'next' class and not the one inside if function.

I hope all of this makes sense :)

Comment: Presumably you want to click the button and have the first step animate, click again and the second should animate, and so on..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem was you were using `.sirina` to animate. That will trigger all the elements to animate. Here, Your if condition dont have any meaning since you are using `.sirina` to animate. Now my answer

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.next').click(function () {
        $('.stiglo').nextAll('.prvi:first').find('.sirina').animate({
                width: '150px'
            }, 1000, function () {

                 $(this).parent().prev('.krug').removeClass('stiglo');

                $(this).parent().next('.krug').animate({
                    borderTopColor: '#E3B009',
                    borderBottomColor: '#E3B009',
                    borderLeftColor: '#E3B009',
                    borderRightColor: '#E3B009'
                }, 1000).addClass('stiglo');
            });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/LbssU/6/)

Comment: Yes, you are right. This one makes sense as it also removes previous classes and animates just the one after that class, so if someone hits next multiple times, it wont behave strange. Thanks Arjun

Comment: Managed to add prev state as well, i think code looks ok:

http://jsfiddle.net/Frenki/LbssU/8/

Thanks again

Comment: @GoranJakovljevic, you are welcome. pls check your code again. If you click 'prev' button even after it become completely black(all 7 divs), and then click next it wont work. So you have to put a condition to keep the '.stiglo' class if it is the first element.

Answer (score 3):

The scope inside this callback refers to the element the `animate()` is execute on:

```
        $('.sirina').animate({
            width: '150px'
        }, 1000, function () {
            // $(this) is $('.sirina') element the callback is executed on
            $(this).parent().next('.krug').animate({
                borderTopColor: '#E3B009',
                borderBottomColor: '#E3B009',
                borderLeftColor: '#E3B009',
                borderRightColor: '#E3B009'
            }, 1000).addClass('stiglo');
        });
```

Inside the click handler the scope is the element the `click()` is attached to, in this case `$('.next')`. You can use closure in order to use this context inside the `animate()` callback.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.next').click(function () {
        var self = this;
        if ($('.sirina').parent().prev('.krug').hasClass('stiglo')) {
            console.log(this);
            $('.sirina').animate({
                width: '150px'
            }, 1000, function () {
                // self is $('.next')[0]
                $(self).parent().next('.krug').animate({
                    borderTopColor: '#E3B009',
                    borderBottomColor: '#E3B009',
                    borderLeftColor: '#E3B009',
                    borderRightColor: '#E3B009'
                }, 1000).addClass('stiglo');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the current index of the element, look

[DEMO VIEW](http://jsfiddle.net/LbssU/5/)

```
    var current=0;

   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.next').click(function () {
        if ($('.sirina').parent().prev('.krug').hasClass('stiglo')) {
            console.log(this);
            $('.sirina').eq(current).animate({
                width: '150px'
            }, 1000, function () {
                current++;
                $('.krug').eq(current).animate({
                    borderTopColor: '#E3B009',
                    borderBottomColor: '#E3B009',
                    borderLeftColor: '#E3B009',
                    borderRightColor: '#E3B009'
                }, 1000).addClass('stiglo');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank You! This is it. I think I can use this code to add also previous button, which would reduce current by 1 (current= current- 1) and just turn around animations ?

Comment: Yes reduce the current index and do a reverse animation